# PostgreSQL: How to include counts of 0

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to count the number of instance of arc_name shows up for each agent id in a single table. Some values should be 0 and I need to see that. I tried using inner and outer joins but I can't see to get the correct output with whatever I try.

Query I'm running:

```
select arc_agt_id, count(arc_name) 
from arcsight.events 
where arc_deviceVendor!='ArcSight'  
group by arc_agt_id
```

Results I'm getting

```
arc_agt_id                | count(arc_name)
--------------------------+----------------------------
30D9Sw1MBABDfYr21UVlCKw== |                        2405
30tpaw1MBABDgIt6vGXvdOw== |                          24
33dnWvVMBABCtK+QmmkJFmw== |                          34
3KO9Aw1MBABDeW7QDfqHLrQ== |                         150
3PqZkM1MBABCAZQUeEsoMyQ== |                          17
3WzBTyFMBABDkGgmV5hkYCg== |                      139401
3go+3yFMBABC6w9nthwL-xA== |                        2626
3jBRoplMBABCLS9DuFdIeEw== |                      214456
3t4uJ1GIBABDVLXw-2ElS8A== |                         156
```

Results I want:

```
arc_agt_id                | count(arc_name)
--------------------------+----------------------------
30D9Sw1MBABDfYr21UVlCKw== |                        2405
30tpaw1MBABDgIt6vGXvdOw== |                          24
33dnWvVMBABCtK+QmmkJFmw== |                          34
3KO9Aw1MBABDeW7QDfqHLrQ== |                         150
3PqZkM1MBABCAZQUeEsoMyQ== |                          17
3WzBTyFMBABDkGgmV5hkYCg== |                      139401
3go+3yFMBABC6w9nthwL-xA== |                        2626
CLS9DuFdIeEw3jBRoplMBAB== |                          0
3UULSLSLS88ujiu8u8u8u88== |                          0
3jBRoplMBABCLS9DuFdIeEw== |                      214456
3t4uJ1GIBABDVLXw-2ElS8A== |                         156
```

Comment: Is there a separate table which contains all possible values of `arc_agt_id`, or do you just want all values which occur in the `arcsight.events` table at least once?

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want conditional aggregation:

```
select arc_agt_id,
       sum(case when arc_deviceVendor <> 'ArcSight' then 1 else 0 end)
from arcsight.events   
group by arc_agt_id
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you!